# Which is the "calling entity" when invoking Terraform with a role from another account?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I am using cross-account authorisation to create AWS resources with Terraform. That is to say:

- I have an account "A" where I have a user.
- I also have an account "B" where I have a role that is authorised to deploy resources within account "B".
- My user account in "A" is authorised to assume the role in account "B".
- When I run Terraform (with the "aws" provider), I have the credentials for user "A" in the aws credentials file.
- My Terraform configuration has the provider block like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "<ARN of roleB>"
  }
}
```

The documentation for the `aws_caller_identity` data source says that it exposes details about "the calling entity", but it is unclear to me which "entity" this should be in my case: is it `userA` or `roleB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have been unable to find any official documentation that specifies which entity this refers to, by experimentation I have determined that "the calling entity" in this case is the role **session** in account "B" (note that while this is related to the role, it is not actually the role itself).

The ARN exposed by this data source looks like

```
"arn:aws:sts::<account B ID>:assumed-role/<name of role B>/<session name>"
```

The `session name` can be specified explicitly in the `assume_role` block, but if it is omitted then it is a semi-random-looking 19-digit number (I'm not sure whether this number is generated by Terraform or AWS).